# In IDE why doesn’t ;(Semicolons) come automatically?

Tags: c, ide

If we write printf then we will automatically get “()”
But why does semicolon not appear with it. I think it would solve a lot of errors.

For printf we get
`printf()`

We should get
`printf();`

Comment: This really depends a *lot* on the IDE you're using, and the rules set up for code completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that's a good suggestion, but often there might be such functions or objects (from the OOP concept) which might have another function following it.

Example (in Javascript):

```
const ref = firestore.collection(db).get();         // get() fn alone

const ref = firestore.collection(db).get().then();  // get() fn followed by then()
```

Or there can be a character at the end of the line.

Example:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){               // '{' present. ';' will cause error
   printf("Hi");                      // ';' required
}                                     // '}' present. ';' will cause error
```

So it's a much more efficient approach to just throw an error every time the compiler detects a missing semicolon. Also, when you use languages such as Python or frameworks/libraries such as Node.JS or React.JS, you won't be required to use a semicolon altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the example. The first one perfect example and I got the answer I wanted. But for the second one you could get `for(){ }` just by writing for. I think program should recognize functions and objects and give the appropriate output. Example(){} for for,if etc and,(); for scanf,printf, etc rather than detecting () and generating ;

Comment: But in the second one, you can also have a multi-line for-loop. So because of this coding convention, which might arise a lot of exceptions as to where to exactly place a semicolon. And throwing a "missing semicolon" error is better than handling those exceptions every now and then.

Comment: Thanks. I came to conclusion that every language have different set of rules so we have to create plug-ins which suit our needs for particular language. For example. In plug-in for C, someone can create a program that will detect printf, scanf, int etc. and generate (); for them and detect for, if etc. and generate (){ } (this is multiline)(I just don’t know how to do it in comment).

Comment: Glad to know. Upvote my answer if you like it :)

Comment: I did upvote it but I didn’t have enough reputations.

Comment: Oh thnx  for it btw

Answer (score 0):

Not all valid c statements end in ';'. Some examples are:

```
#include <file> //can't put ; here
macro(arg) //won't work here too
if(true) //wont work here
```

and the like. C isn't built like python after all.

Comment: I didn’t say I want semicolon on each line. As you know that if you type printf then it will automatically become printf() but I want to know why not printf();. Same goes for scanf. For int, float … it could generate ; in the end. For if, switch, etc it generates (){} which does not include semicolon. Since programs usually recognize the functions and give the required out put but I wanted to know why semicolon is not added.